# Why am I getting this error message "Error: Unknown option: --user"

Tags: adb, 4.4-kitkat

I have a Samsung T520, KitKat 4.4.2

I have not rooted my tab...I am trying to use adb commands to uninstall bloatware but I am getting the following error:

**Error: Unknown option: --user**

Anyone know why this is happening? I have had no issue using this command on other devices.

The command I used was for example

```
pm uninstall --user 0 com.android.email
```

Comment: Because the device is running an old Android version, and multi-user was just introduced with Android 5 (Lollipop) – except for a few tablets which had it earlier? Can you add another user to your device? If not, then it's this.

Comment: Your pm command doesn't take that flag/argument, hence the error. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-4.4.2_r1/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#1519 // It would be nice if somebody explains what is going on here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-4.4.2_r1/cmds/pm/src/com/android/commands/pm/Pm.java#1093 I think that running pm uninstall command would delete the package for all users in Android 4.4.2